# Sqlite: how to update only empty fields

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hi and thanks for your help,

I am really new to SQL, so I kindly ask your help.

I did my research, but so far I have not been able to find a solution.

I have a partiality populated column is my Sqlite database.

Some fields are empty, some contain a number.

I need to populate only the empty fields with the number 60000.

Thank for ant help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

Update tablename 
SET number = 60000 
where field IS NULL

Comment: @HSQL Please **[format](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)** code in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `UPDATE` with `WHERE columnname IS NULL`

```
UPDATE yourtable
   SET yourcolumn = 60000
 WHERE yourcolumn IS NULL
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d4784/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
update t
    set col = 60000
    where col is null;
```

That is, you can add a `where` clause to the `update` statement to limit the rows that are affected.